# Python OCR - Captcha

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

I must be able to read captchas in my code.

The Captcha consists of lines of # in different colors. (HTML format)

I turn the HTML code to image and use the ImageEnhance from PIL to remove noise and increase the contrast and i get something like this:
[image: clear captcha]

but still I am not able to convert the bild to string using pytesseract. I get a sting with length of 0. I have also tried both tools from pyocr and they could not help me either.
I would be really grateful if some one can help me.

```
def convert_captcha_to_string(captcha_path):
    captcha_image = Image.open(captcha_path)
    config = "--psm 6 -l eng"
    captcha_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(captcha_image, config=config)
    print(captcha_text)
    return captcha_text
```